# Maven dependency ordering

Tags: maven

hi 
I was wondering whether anyone knows of a way to order which dependencies get called first. The issue I have is that I am including geronimo jaxws spec 2.2, but the jre version of javax.xml.ws.Service is being picked up instead of the dependency version. I tried putting the dependency first on the dependency list and tried dependency-management to no success (maybe I am using it wrong).  When in eclipse i can tell it to pick up the jars in maven dependencies first, but i don't know how to do that in maven.

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you facing any issue with this?You can't give higher preference to a dependent jar as compared to jdk. A similar bug was already raised with gernonimo jaxws and they've fixed the issue by adding new properties to metadata for jar. Please follow the link for more info https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-4927

Comment: Cheers thanks - putting the relevant geronimo jars in the endorsed directorry solved the issue. Looks like the geronimo guys are working on it. I think it is for the jaxb jar as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can order the dependencies in maven in the way you want. You'll have to use java import statements to select which Service you want to use.

One trick to help diagnose these kind of issues is to use: mvn dependency:tree. That will at least confirm your Geronimo dependency is being pulled in correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is that it will be the same package signature in java - javax.xml.ws.Service. It is imported by the dependency and by the jre. The dependency is a newer version but the jre version gets picked up instead.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do it within maven but one possible solution, which i am using at present, is to put the required jars into the jre/lib/endorsed directory (creating the endorsed directory if it doesn't exist). The jaxws and jaxb jars came into Java 6 and weren't there for Java 5. The jre versions will be used by maven where they exist regardless of whether the dependencies you define are newer or not. Placing them into the endorsed directory overrides the jre versions.